# Partial text hiding in Swift TextField

Tags: ios, swift, string, textfield, mask

I use masking like (555) 555-5555, but I also want it to look like (555) 5 ** - ****. What can I do to mask the user like this when entering text?

mask func:

```
func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String, replacmentCharacter: Character) -> String {
    var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
        guard index < pureNumber.count else { return pureNumber }
        let stringIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: index)
        let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
        guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
        pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
    }
    return pureNumber
}
```

usage:

```
sender.text = textString.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: "(###) ###-####", replacmentCharacter: "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension on `String` to mask all the digits except the country code numbers (any digit between rounded brackets). Note that there could definitely be some performance improvements for this function, but I hope it will at least help you to get started:

```
extension String {

    func masked(replacementCharacter: Character = "*") -> String {
        let regex = "\\(.*?\\)"
        let ranges = self.ranges(pattern: regex)
        func isContained(_ index: Int) -> Bool {
            for range in ranges {
                if index > range.location && index < range.location + range.length - 1 {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        var maskedString = String()
        for (index, character) in self.enumerated() {
            if isContained(index) {
                maskedString.append(character)
            } else {
                if String(character).isDigit {
                    maskedString.append(replacementCharacter)
                } else {
                    maskedString.append(character)
                }
            }
        }
        return maskedString
    }
}
```

These are some extensions that I'm using in the code above:

```
extension String {

    var isDigit: Bool {
        CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: self))
    }

    func ranges(pattern: String) -> [NSRange] {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        return regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count)).map { $0.range }
    }

    subscript (bounds: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.upperBound)
        return String(self[start...end])
    }

    subscript (bounds: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.upperBound)
        return String(self[start..<end])
    }
}
```

If you just want to mask any digit from your string (even digits within parentheses), you can simplify to this:

```
extension String {

    func masked(replacementCharacter: Character = "*") -> String {
        var maskedString = String()
        for character in self {
            if String(character).isDigit {
                maskedString.append(replacementCharacter)
            } else {
                maskedString.append(character)
            }
        }
        return maskedString
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use it like so:

```
let input = "(123) 456-7890"
let output = input.masked()
// Prints (123) ***-****
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for TextField, not for string.